# three table relationship on django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to do something very basic here with three models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
   country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
   company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   continent = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class CountryProfile(models.Model):
   country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
   minimum_wage = models.IntField()

class Country(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Basically, Car points to Country, and CountryProfile also points to Country. I was wondering how I could get all car's company names with continent equal to something and minimum wage associated with the country of a respective car company, without having to do two db calls.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Picking up the `Country`'s details while querying for a `Car` is easy. `Car` has a foreign key pointing to `Country` and `select_related()` will do the trick.

```
Car.objects.select_related().filter()
```

However (as far as I know; please correct me if I am wrong) Django doesn't allow you to select "reverse relationships" using the `select_related()` call. This means you cannot pick up `CountryProfile` using a `select_related` call from `Country`. Which in turn means that you'd end up firing two queries.

If you are using Django 1.2 and are willing to fall back to [raw SQL queries](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) then you can get `Car` instances with additional information using a single (join) query.

Comment: So, I guess there's no more efficient way to do this. Thanks for the response!

Comment: There are a couple of options if you don't mind stepping away from the Django ORM. 

1) as I said above, use a combination of Django ORM and a custom SQL query. 

2) This one is way more radical. Use SQLAlchemy to handle your joins in this case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154331/sqlalchemy-and-django-is-it-production-ready/1155407#1155407 for an example.