# Sqlalchemy to django orm

Tags: python, django, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a command line script that has sqlalchemy. They look as follows:

```
class TimestampMixin(object):
    created_date = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())

class DataSource(Base, TimestampMixin):
    """DataSource object"""
    __tablename__ = 'data_source'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    external_location = Column(String)
    games = relationship('Game', backref="data_source")
```

Now I want to take the same models and put it into a django app. I can do it by hand as follows:

```
class TimestampMixin(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class DataSource(TimestampMixin):
    """DataSource object"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    external_location = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'data_source'
```

I was wondering if there is a better way. It wouldn't be so bad to start as I only have 9 models, but I would rather not upkeep them. Is there a better(standardized) approach? With djanog I would want to still be able to use things like DjangoRestFramework and DjangoForms. I'm not sure if they work with sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use either Django ORM or SQLAlchemy.

If you want to use SQLAlchemy database in django, what you can do is:

1. Create a django project.
2. Update Database settings with desired database's configuration.
3. Run command: `python manage.py inspectdb`

This will return the model structure which can be used in Django without changing the database.

You can check it here in detail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154331/sqlalchemy-and-django-is-it-production-ready) SO answer about using SQLAlchemy and Django together.